# Unhandled String in incorrect Format

Tags: c#, string, casting

Basically refreshing some C# knowledge making a converter; I'm trying to make a window pop up when no numbers are in the `textbox` but when I click the `button` I get this error:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

```
private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Killogram convertion

        double i = double.Parse(txtboxAmount.Text);
        if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem == "KG" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem == "LB")
        {
            double conver = i * 2.20462262185;
            double converdec = Math.Round((Double)conver, 2);
            txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + converdec;
        }

        if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem == "LB" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem == "KG")
        {
            double conver = i / 2.2046;
            double converdec = Math.Round((Double)conver, 2);
            txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + converdec;
        }

        if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem == "ST" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem == "KG")
        {
            double conver = i * 6.35;
            double converdec = Math.Round((Double)conver, 2);
            txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + converdec;
        }

        // Pound convertion


        if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem == "LB" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem == "ST")
        {
            double conver = i / 14;
            double converdec = Math.Round((Double)conver, 2);
            txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + converdec;
        }

        if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem == "ST" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem == "LB")
        {
            double conver = i / 14;
            double converdec = Math.Round((Double)conver, 2);
            txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + converdec;
        }

        if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem == "LB" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem == "KG")
        {
            double conver = i / 2.205;
            double converdec = Math.Round((Double)conver, 2);
            txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + converdec;
        }

        // Stone convertion

        if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem == "ST" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem == "LB")
        {
            double conver = i * 14;
            double converdec = Math.Round((Double)conver, 2);
            txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + converdec;
        }

        if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem == "LB" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem == "ST")
        {
            double conver = i / 14;
            double converdec = Math.Round((Double)conver, 2);
            txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + converdec;
        }

        if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem == "LB" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem == "KG")
        {
            double conver = i / 2.205;
            double converdec = Math.Round((Double)conver, 2);
            txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + converdec;
        }

        else if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem == null && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid weight amount and/or select a unit of measurement.");
        }

    }
```

The line causing the issues is below I string turning it into a string with to string but no luck

```
double i = double.Parse(txtboxAmount.Text);
```

Comment: Use `double.TryParse()` for extra luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) to fail gracefully:

```
var text = "123.4";

double result;

if (double.TryParse(text, out result))
{
    // do something
}
```

The other thing to account for might be the culture, if you use a French system and input English notation,

i.e. `.` instead of `,` it will fail parsing your input.

```
if (double.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat, out result))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I thought of using TryParse but what do I put as a result??

Comment: Should I try a different way of approaching this?